# Redimension numpy array dynamically

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have an array, lets say:

```
A = np.array([1., 2.])
```

I can add a new dimension by simply doing something like:

```
def redim(arr):
   return arr[:, None]
```

Now, I want to add extra dimensions dynamically in this manner:

```
def redim(arr, dims):
   return arr[dims]
```

So I can do things like:

```
redim(A, [:, None])
redim(A, [None, :])
redim(A, [none, :, None])
```

Does anybody know if this is even possible?

What kind of second argument should it be so I can modify it dynamically? (string, obj, list)?
How do I `connect` both arguments to get the expanded array?

I know I can go the expand_dims route, but if there is a way to define all the expanded dimensions in one swipe, my code will be much clearer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [`reshape`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) is what you are looking for.

If string theory taught us one thing, it is that everything requires 11 dimensions:

```
>>> A = np.array([1,2])
>>> A = A.reshape((2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
>>> A
array([[[[[[[[[[[1]]]]]]]]]],






   [[[[[[[[[[2]]]]]]]]]]])
```

And now you can get slices along any dimension:

```
>>> A[1,:,:,:,:,0]
array([[[[[[[[[2]]]]]]]]])
```

The only requirement when using reshape is that your total number of elements is unchanged (i.e. the product of dimensions must be unchanged between the first and second shape)

**Edit**

If you want to use slices anyway, you have to pass a `tuple` of arguments, like this:

```
def redim(a, dims):
    return a[dims]

>>> redim(A, (slice(None), None, slice(None), None))
```

Numpy arrays have a special behaviour when passed tuple of arguments (which is exactly what multi-indexing like `A[1,2,:]` does under the cover), and if you want to wrap calls to the `[]` operator, you actually have to comply with the `np.ndarray.__getitem__` function signature.

To get multidimensional indices, it expects a tuple of ints, `None` or `slice` objects (which are the objects created when using slice notations, e.g. `A[1:2] <=> A.__getitem__(slice(1,2))`). It is quite cumbersome to work with, but you can wrap all numpy operations if you stick to the numpy conventions for arrays (summarized [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html))

Comment: `reshape` returns a view of the original array, and doesn't modify the original array.  If you want to `redim` in place, you must use `A = A.reshape(newshape)` as in this answer, or you can use `A.resize(newshape)` or `A.shape = newshape` to do it truly in-place.